# Exposed metal rod in the wall. What is it? What should I do?

Tags: electrical

[image]

I tried removing some loose plaster and exposed a thin steel rod running up the wall. It seems to have had a coving which has rusted (maybe burnt?) off.

My guess is that it is the earth for the electrics but that is completely a guess. A friend suggested it could be the old wiring but doesn’t look like wire...

Any idea what it is and what I should do? Is it safe?

Cheers

Comment: Is there a cupboard under those stairs where you can see an end of the mystery item?

Comment: What country is this located in?

Comment: Possibly an old window opening that has been bricked in.

Comment: Enlarging the picture, that really does look like deteriorating insulation of some type..

Comment: What is to the left of the rod ? While it does look like a ground rod - but oddly turns and insulated. Is it solid metal or possibly hollow tube? If Hollow maybe a water line for radiators ?  Is this upper or lower level - what is in proximity to the ends of it ? I am with @PaulLogan on this one - seems the odd shape and insulation is a framing of some sort to close off an old window, why I would like to know the texture to the left - matching brick or mismatch/ no brick.

Comment: The bricks to the left seems to have a “running bond”, while the bricks to the right seem to be more of a modified “stack bond”. Bricks on left could be structural and bricks on right are probably “infill” and probably not installed at the same time.

Comment: maybe get a metal detector and see where it goes. Again where in the world is this and how old is the house?

Comment: I thought at first glance it may be rusted out conduit, after looking closer it appears to be a little small for conduit.

Comment: looking close, especially at the bottom it looks like flat romex-like wire in conduit to me. (you can see it twisting in the horizontal part).  Obviously you'd want to determine if it is active before just covering it back up.

Answer (score 1):

Before electricity, gas lighting was common in homes and commercial buildings.  When electric lighting began replacing gas lighting, sometimes gas piping was disconnected from gas and used for electric lighting.  There are even some reports that for a time, gas piping was installed new for electric lighting - the idea was that just in case electricity turned out to be a novelty or fad, the piping would be in place for gas lights.

The picture is not very clear but it appears to be a very corroded pipe with a gray flat cable in it.

The bend in the pipe is sharp, unlike electrical conduit, which is usually bent with a gentle sweep.  Judging from the brickwork, the plaster, the stair stringer, and the advanced deterioration of the pipe, it could be 100+ years old.

I believe it is most likely old gas / plumbing pipe being used for electrical.  The gray flat cable in the pipe might be UF - nonmetallic cable rated for wet locations - that's typically the only flat gray cable you see in recent years.  However the current conventions for color coding the jackets of nonmetallic cables have not been around nearly as long as this structure, so it may be something else.

Comment: Depends on where this is located but that looks like standard "twin&earth" cable used for socket circuits in the UK.

Answer (score -1):

The exposed metal does not appear to be stranded cable, thus I doubt it is electrical. The compromise in the plaster appears to continue upward, as does the metal in question. I suggest it could be structural, with settling/aging affecting the structure, causing the plaster to break at the shear line (this metal). Additional clues and images of the surrounding wall /other side of the face would help...

Perhaps identifying the cause of the crumbling/damaged plaster would give additional clues as to the nature of this metal.